# SIGTRAP selecting a specific UITableViewCell on iOS 6.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a UITableView with cells grouped together in a single section. When I select a particular UITableViewCell the app crashes. It works well when I select other cells.
It works on all iOS versions except for iOS 6.1.3.

The stack trace from Crittercism

```
Threads
_________________________________
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     CoreFoundation                        0x319b268a CFRelease + 18
1     APP_NAME                              0x000fdd3b 0x000b9000 + 281915
2     APP_NAME                              0x000fe7d7 0x000b9000 + 284631
3     UIKit                                 0x3389f579 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 365
4     UIKit                                 0x338f41f7 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 27
5     UIKit                                 0x338f413d -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 29
6     UIKit                                 0x338f4021 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 33
7     UIKit                                 0x338f3f4d -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 273
8     UIKit                                 0x338f3699 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 65
9     UIKit                                 0x338f3581 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 325
10   UIKit                                  0x338e1b5b -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 859
11   UIKit                                  0x338e17fb -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 39
12   APP_NAME                               0x000e8d81 0x000b9000 + 195969
13   UIKit                                  0x3394231d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 877
14   UIKit                                  0x339c4da9 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 157
15   Foundation                             0x32380657 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 451
16   CoreFoundation                         0x31a46857 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 15
17   CoreFoundation                         0x31a46503 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 275
18   CoreFoundation                         0x31a45177 __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
19   CoreFoundation                         0x319b823d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
20   CoreFoundation                         0x319b80c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
21   GraphicsServices                       0x3559733b GSEventRunModal + 75
22   UIKit                                  0x338d42b9 UIApplicationMain + 1121
23   APP_NAME                               0x000e996b 0x000b9000 + 199019
```

The code that is called didSelectRowAtIndexPath is (nothing special).

```
 else if(indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==3) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier" sender:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in loading your new view controller – do you have a symbolicated crash log? The answer lies in examining the two methods just below `CFRelease` in the stack trace.

Comment: used atos -arch -armv7 ... to symbolicate the report. I found that the app crashes on
-[FBUserSettingsViewController updateControls] (in APP_NAME) (FBUserSettingsViewController.m:262)
Is this a facebook SDK bug?

Comment: I don't know, I'd ask a new question with the symbolicated crash report.